# Preventing automatic offsetting when opening a new window

Tags: c#, wpf, window, showdialog

In WPF, when a new Window is shown, it is offset by maybe 10 pixels horizontally and vertically. Is there an easy way to prevent this, so the window opens directly over the one that triggered it? (They are the same size - consider it similar to an installer's behavior)

Comment: If "the one that triggered it" is a `Window` that's the parent of this new Window, go with `WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner"` [Window.WindowStartupLocation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.windowstartuplocation.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set the `WindowStartupLocation` property of all windows to `CenterScreen` value.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the Left and Top properties of the new window to be the same as the owner window.
You should do this before you call the Show or ShowDialog methods.

Good luck,

M. Moshe